# Median survival time for stratified Cox model

Tags: survival, cox-model

I have a dataset of 30,000 patients who are matched by surgical procedure.  My main exposure of interest is if the patient got regional anesthesia during surgery or did not.  I have 27 different surgical procedure types, so instead of including 26 dummy variables in my Cox regression model, I stratified on them.  In addition to the main exposure of interest in the model (regional anesthesia/no regional anesthesia), I have 3 other covariates I'm controlling for...Is there a simple way to calculate median survival for the patients who got regional anesthesia and for those that did not? Or would I have to calculate median survival for these two groups for all 27 strata since they all have different baseline hazards?

Comment: Let me suggest you to read something about Laplace regression http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/bimj.200900310/abstract

Comment: Regarding the paper @andrea suggested, you may also want to have a look at this: http://www.econ.uiuc.edu/~roger/research/crq/note.pdf

Comment: And in response to the letter that @MånsT linked... http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/bimj.201100103/abstract?deniedAccessCustomisedMessage=&userIsAuthenticated=false